# Miniseries involving virtual reality, warring secret societies

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was aired in the early-mid 90's, when virtual reality was starting to be developed, VR and holograms were a big part of the story. Also two secret societies were feuding, one used a rhinoceros as its symbol. It starred Jim Belushi, Dana Delaney and *maybe* Ernie Hudson.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jim Belushi, Dana Delaney and Ernie Hudson starred in *[Wild Palms](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106175/)* (1993)

> *A multi-national corporation attempts to take over America while small pockets of resistance hold out against rampant technology.*

Comment: Beat me to it by just a bit. :-D